# How to add seconds with datetime in golang

Tags: go

I have a date `2018-07-10 09:35:39` and seconds `10`.
Now I want to add given seconds to DateTime.

So the final result should be `2018-07-10 09:35:49`

I have tried as follow : -

```
    Mydate := 2018-07-10 09:35:39
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
    Seconds := 10
    MydateParse, _ := time.Parse(layout, Mydate)
    FinalDate := MydateParse.Add(time.Second * Seconds)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? Show your code.

Comment: You might want to explain what your error is, and whether you've tried my answer. Otherwise it will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code, but you only answered half of my question. The other half is: What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Aside from that, the code you've included is obviously wrong, as it won't even compile. You're also ignoring errors. Never do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date is of type [Time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/):

```
time.Add(10 * time.Second)
```

EDIT: In your case, it seems as though you just need to put your date in quotes, to make it a string:

```
Mydate := "2018-07-10 09:35:39"
```

It might be useful to check the error from Parse()

Comment: And what if the date is A DateTime ?